# Firebase retrieving all data not working on iOS 10+ devices

Tags: objective-c, iphone, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ios10

I am working with Firebase database where I have stored values in JSON format. Now, while I am trying to retrieve data on my iPad with iOS 9.3, it worked fine.

But with same code when I tried to fetch all data on iPhone 5 with iOS 10.2.1, it didn't fetch all results but it fetches only few part of records.

Here is what I have done :

```
NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://MYApp-d1111.firebaseio.com"];
    FIRDatabaseReference *ref = [[FIRDatabase database] referenceFromURL:strUrl];
    [ref observeSingleEventOfType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {
        NSDictionary *post = snapshot.value;
        NSLog(@" ********** %@", post);
    }];
```

So issue is simple & straight when I tried this code on devices with iOS version less than 10 it fetches all data. But if I try same code on devices with 10+ iOS version than its not fetching all data, but a small part of data.

Can anyone help me to find out the solution. Any references or hint will be highly appreciated.

Thanks & regards,
Mayur